# Не записываются данные в таблицу sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3, discord.py

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM userinfo where id={int(message.author.id)+int(message.guild.id)}")
    if cursor.fetchone()==None:
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO userinfo VALUES ({int(message.author.id)+int(message.guild.id)}, 0, 1)")
        conn.commit()
    else:
        pass
    conn.commit()
    # if len(message.content) >=10:
    id = int(message.author.id)+int(message.guild.id)
    for row in cursor.execute(f"SELECT xp, lvl FROM userinfo where id={id}"):
        reward = random.randint(5,25)
        xp=row[0]+reward
        level=row[1]
        need = round(((90+level)*level)+level*(level+round((level*2)*level)))
        if level == 0:
            level = 1
            if xp >= need:
                lvl=int(level)+1
                await message.channel.send(f'Поздравляю! {message.author.mention} перешёл на уровень {lvl}!!!')
        cursor.execute(f'UPDATE userinfo SET xp={xp}, lvl={lvl} where id={id}')
    conn.commit()
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

---

При получении данных о пользователе, постоянно возвращается результат

> xp = 0 lvl = 1 need = 94

Answer (score 0):

У тебя проблема заключается в том, что ты не закрываешь соединение.
Попробуй сделать вот так:

```
def req_to_db(req,need_to_commit=False):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(req)
    cursor.fetchall()
    if(need_to_commit):
        cursor.commit()
    conn.close()

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    result = req_to_db(f"SELECT id FROM userinfo where id={int(message.author.id)+int(message.guild.id)}")
    if [x[0] for x in result]==[]:
        result = req_to_db(f"INSERT INTO userinfo VALUES ({int(message.author.id)+int(message.guild.id)}, 0, 1)",need_to_commit=True)
    id = int(message.author.id)+int(message.guild.id)
    for row in req_to_db(f"SELECT xp, lvl FROM userinfo where id={id}"):
        reward = random.randint(5,25)
        xp=row[0]+reward
        level=row[1]
        need = round(((90+level)*level)+level*(level+round((level*2)*level)))
        if level == 0:
            level = 1
            if xp >= need:
                lvl=int(level)+1
                await message.channel.send(f'Поздравляю! {message.author.mention} перешёл на уровень {lvl}!!!')
        req_to_db(f'UPDATE userinfo SET xp={xp}, lvl={lvl} where id={id}', need_to_commit=True)
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Должно сработать. Если не хочешь изменять свой код, то просто закрывай соединение в конце функции(перед await).